# If my app deletes a post it made to a user's wall, will all likes and shares made by other people also be deleted?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-apps, facebook-page, facebook-wall

Lets say I have a FB app I've created, and for whatever reason the server code for the app is responsible for posting stories to the app user's wall (using a token).

Now let's say we want to take down that post at a later date - easy, right? Because the app created the post, it owns it, and using the ID it received originally it can take that post down. (I presume the ID I get back is actually an "object id" referring to my content, rather than specifically to the post on the user's wall - correct?)

Here's the thing though. What if one or more friends of the user shared that story to their own wall - what if this happened a number of times, spreading through the friend relationship tree further and further. Does my app still have the power to remove all of these posts, because it created the original post?

Additionally, what if the original user deleted the post themselves from their wall, but not until it had been shared by his/her friends? Would this have the same effect (delete everywhere), or would it only be that one specific post being removed? Would my app get an error when it tried to delete the post itself if the post had already been deleted by the user?

The reason I ask is because, if my app deleted the original post that it made to the user's wall, I would want *all* of the shared posts or likes to also be deleted, no matter where they were down the friend chain. I don't want to delete my original post and assume all is well, only to discover that because it was shared several times down the chain that it is still visible somewhere.

In case it's relevant, the "post" my app will make would require a custom image and a specific return URL - I tried the `/user_id/links` graph API and it didnt work (there's a bug with it). So I'd be most likely using `/user_id/feed` to make the post.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> if my app deleted the original post that it made to the user's wall, would *all* of the shared posts also be deleted from everywhere?

Yes

> What if the original user deleted the post themselves from their wall, but not until it had been shared by his/her friends? Would this have the same effect?

Yes

How did I know this? I tested it.

I posted a status update to a test user Betty

[image: Betty]

Then had three other test users share it one after the other

[image: All the friends share it]

So Tom shared it > Joe shared what Tom shared > Patricia shared what Joe shared

Then for completeness I had Betty share it again

[image: Betty shares again]

On delete, all posts are gone from all test users, including the re-share Betty made.

As long as the user shares via the action link all subsequent shares will be deleted if the original is deleted.

But if the user manually copies it or saves a photo then re-uploads then no.

*In terms of documentation, you have to bite bullet and realize there is no comprehensive documentation for Facebook and not all Facebook engineers know all features about Facebook. There are many items that haven't been able to get a word from Facebook about, and that's when I test things. That's what developers do. Create new test paths, do coverages, make branches and arrive at a conclusion*

Comment: +1 Great stuff! They should honestly just copy this post into the documentation.  Including the last paragraph!

Comment: FYI I've had this confirmed by Facebook (all re-shares are deleted if post is removed), so this is - as far as I'm concerned) - exactly the correct answer. Thanks again phwd.

Answer (score 1):

If you post a link on your user's wall, the shared content cannot be deleted
where as if you post a photo, it will be deleted

Comment: The post I have in mind would require a custom image and a specific return URL - I tried the `/user_id/links` graph API and it didnt work (there's a bug with it). So I'd be most likely using `/user_id/feed` to make the post. Would that still mean that if anyone shared the story from the user's wall that my app could not remove them?

Comment: Yes, you will not able to remove the child posts if they share an URL

Comment: Interesting. That's kinda what I first thought, before considering the POST ID to be a reference to the content as an object, rather than the post itself. Is there any official documentation that you know of that confirms your answer? This work is for a client and there's nothing better than official documentation to make a point! cheers :)

Comment: I can't give you an official documentation kind of. But try implementing and you will get to know yourself

Comment: Yeah I'm trying to avoid any dev work because if it cant be done then it changes the game quite a lot, and we'll end up doing something else. Thanks for your input, if I dont get any other answers today i'll accept yours as correct.

Answer (score 1):

If you delete a post (whether it was a link, status update, photo etc), deleting will delete all Likes and Comments from the Object, as well as the related newsfeeds from anyone connected to the object (e.g. it will remove things like `Friend has commented on Someone's post` etc).

It won't, however, delete any `re-shares` of that post from users' timeline.

Comment: Right, this is exactly the point I wanted to clarify - thank you. So if my app makes a post to someone's wall, and one of their friends shares it to their own wall, then essentially there's two objects in existence and deleting one will not delete the other, right?

Do you know if there is a web page documenting this behaviour?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Resharing essentially creates a copy of the original object, but posts it as a new object to the user's timeline. Unfortunately, I couldn't find any documentation relating to this.

Comment: Curiously, I've received a response to the same question that I placed on the deveoper group on Facebook itself, from another dev, who says he has tested my situation and confirms that any shared posts *will* be deleted. Only if people were to copy & paste the story would those stories not be deleted (which seems obvious).

Comment: I've tested the `Share` option too, but the shared copies weren't deleted once the original post was... strange...

Comment: All the more reason for me to try to find some sort of official documentation! Pity none seems to exist. Thanks for your help.